# Spring boot admin not showing secured endpoints of spring boot client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

Installed spring boot admin and server.
All client endpoints are visible in spring boot admin but after adding security dependency in client secured endpoints are not visible in admin.
Provided credentials of admin and client in application.yaml of client.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Firstly, you need to share user and password from admin-client, this can be configured in yml file:

```
spring.boot.admin.client:
    url: http://localhost:8080
    instance:
      metadata:
        user.name: ${spring.security.user.name}
        user.password: ${spring.security.user.password}
```

Also you need to enable http basic in security config, because SBA server then uses this metadata to make http calls.

source: https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.2.3/#_securing_client_actuator_endpoints